# Why does the vertical bar disappear in one cell of my table?

Tags: tables

For some reason, the third vertical bar fails to appear in the third last row. Why?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & & & \\ \hline
 & & &  \\ \hline
 & & & \\ \hline
 & & & \\ \hline
 &  & &  \\ \hline
 &  &  & \\ \hline
 &  & & \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: The code you posted does not produce the result in your image, can you post code that actually does so? Edit: You should have four columns in the table specification though, or have one less `&` in each row.

Comment: But I want to just do the vertical bar on the third line does not appear

Comment: But it's impossible for us to say for certain why it happens if you don't show us the code! You don't have a `\multicolumn` for example, in the third last row?

Comment: There is no reason for the rule not to appear; if I compile the code, I get all rules as expected. Don't ask twice the same question: you can simply edit the first if you have information to add.