# How to make the third vertical bar disappear in the third row of my table?

Tags: tables

How to make the third vertical bar disappear in the third row of my table?[image]

Comment: What code do you use?

Comment: I don't get it. First you ask why this happens in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165708/why-does-the-vertical-bar-disappear-in-one-cell-of-my-table, here you ask *how* to make this happen. Why two questions?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I retitled the question you mention. Perhaps my interpretation of the question was incorrect. In that case, those two questions are duplication of each other.

Comment: @Jubobs I see. Yes, they look like duplicates, so we can close the first one. benedito: You could have edited your first question instead of asking a new one. If an edit changes the meaning of your question, please roll back that edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{|p{.25\textwidth}}|}
\hline
 & &  \\ \hline
 & &   \\ \hline
 & &  \\ \hline
 & &  \\ \hline
 &  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}  \\ \hline
 &  &   \\ \hline
 &  &  \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]